# Hide Loki query results that have a zero value

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I'm creating a Grafana dashboard from a Loki query:

```
(sum(rate({namespace="namespace", level="error"}[1m])) by (cluster, container, level, namespace))
```

The "Stat" graph I chose looks like this:

[image]

How can I hide the containers that have a zero value? It's worth mentioning that they are not exactly zero, I'm just hiding decimals.

Comment: You can use `>0.5` in your query, or use transformation Filter by value. But are you sure you should? You'll have constantly changing number of frames on panel, and thus changing layout. Usually it's not a good thing. Maybe sorting will do?

Comment: I tried adding transform filters, but the only fields that were available to me were the container names, so I had to create a transform filter on each result which in my case, were a lot of different containers. The below answer worked out for me :)

Comment: List of fields in transformation behaved like this because you haven't set type of your query to Instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not hiding, but you exclude low values on the query level, e.g.:

```
sum(
  rate(
    {
       namespace="namespace",
       level="error"
     }[1m]
  )
) by (cluster, container, level, namespace)<0.9
```

Or use (sligthly complicated) Grafana transformation `Filter data by values`.

Comment: Thank you, the solution was `>0.9` instead of `<0.9` :)

Comment: @Daniel yeah, sorry a typo

Comment: A couple things to mention: Grafana uses rounding when specifying *Decimals* in Standard panel options, so instead of `>0.9` it should be `>=0.5` to filter out all values that will appear as 0. And even if it weren't using 0.9 would result in not entirely correct behavior for values between 0.9 and 1; in that imagined scenario it should be `>=1` then. cc @Daniel

Comment: Also, @Daniel, consider upvoting this answer if it was useful for you.